# pymodbus to read temp from device

Tags: python

I am trying to us pymodbus to read data from a temperature and pressure device, but it seems the output from my readings is always `None`.

Here is my code

```
import pymodbus
import serial
from pymodbus.pdu import ModBusRequest
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as MC
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusRtuFramer

c = MC(method='rtu',port='/dev/ttyUSB1',stopbits=1,
       bytesize=8,parity='E',baudrate=9600)
con = c.connect()
print con

r = c.read_input_registers(0056,4,unit=0x0a)
print r

c. close()
```

`print r` always returns `None`.  Did anyone ever get this working?  If so, do you have any advice?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but not with a raspberry pi.